# I miss 10 rep points

Tags: support, reputation

This time I'm pretty sure: I had 9702 yesterday and two upvotes on an answer and one on a question. But my total rep is 9717. Ten more or less don't matter, but strange it seems to me...

I gained ten reps recently without notification. Is this the reversal or again a recalculation?

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you see anything in your reputation history for today?

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature. It's a feature which allows a single user to irreversibly delete a thread... (I have no complaints about this feature though, even if it is a bit annoying to be on the receiving end of it.)

Comment: @ArthurFischer yes a link to this deleted question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174572/calculation-of-3-degrees-over-5-meters/174582#174582 but I can't remember that I posted something there... gimme 330 reps then I can...

Comment: @draks... Your answer (actually, everything in that question) dates back to July 2012. From what I can tell, the missing 10 points is essentially what Asaf describes: your answer was downvoted bringing it to +1/-1 (net 0 score). Another answer was also downvoted to the same effect, and then the question fit one of the criteria for automatic deletion, which happened soon after.

Comment: @Asaf I see a big problem with this behavior. It means that users who spent their time composing answers to questions have their answers deleted simply because some users did not like the question (e.g. missing context). These answers may have been helpful to many future readers. Further, it may serve to alienate users whose answers were deleted in this manner. It is especially problematic that normal users cannot vote to undelete. Using downvoting in this manner to trigger an irreversible deletion is imo  **serious abuse of downvoting**

Comment: @Bill: I knew that you are going to make this comment. The moment I started typing my comment, I knew you are bound to write yours and I already knew what its content would be, before seeing you even left me a reply. I have zero intentions of arguing about this, which is why I haven't brought this up before. I did spend the last month or two thinking about this behavior, and I came to the conclusion that while it does annoy me from time to time, I don't have that big of a problem with this particular behavior for various reasons I'm too lazy to begin writing down here.

Comment: Before this ends in another comment battle, please open another thread concerning if this behaviour is good or bad...thx

Comment: I miss this breakfast cereal from my childhood, Puffa Puffa Rice https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tLNlTq79UQ4

Comment: @BillDubuque I've asked a related question [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/15126/is-it-appropriate-to-downvote-answers-for-the-sake-of-deleting-a-question).

Comment: @BillDubuque, The other day, I was trying to find a detailed response I typed up from about a month ago. I put a LOT of time into it, and it took at least half an hour to LaTeX. It garnered 1 or maybe 2 upvotes. I noticed yesterday that, after clicking "show rep from deleted answers" that the answer had since received downvotes long after it was posted, allowing the entire thread to be deleted. Needless to say, I wasn't happy.  Point being, I completely agree with you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's a user which goes around and downvotes answers to closed questions with negative votes, so the automatic cleanup process will delete them.

This happens with an hour or two after the downvote, so it's hard to miss.

I've seen this behavior more than several times in my profile, as well I caught it "live" last night when I saw the downvote before the deletion occurred.

Answer (score 7):

If you look at [your reputation tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/19341/draks?tab=reputation) in your profile and check the "show removed posts" checkbox at the bottom of it, you'll see where the 10 reputation went.

You're almost at 10,000 reputation, at which point you'll also see links to the removed posts and will be able to see them, who deleted them, etc.

Comment: Of course, in this particular situation, the deletion will be attributed to Community, and no amount of rep will give someone a list of who downvoted the answer. So additional rep will help someone see where the rep went, but it won't help attribute the person responsible. (Not that I am too worried about the deletions at hand here, I don't see them as a problem.)